# Objective vs Subjective Pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns, prepositional-objects

While reading *The Rose of Battle* (W.B Yeats) I came across this line

> For him who hears love sing and never cease

My question is whether the pronoun here should be subjective or objective (as in for **he** who hears), I have seen both in many different works and I am wondering if there be certain rules that govern this, or at least what is considered the more sophisticated view.

Comment: Surely you are not impugning the mastery of Yeats, are you now? :)

Comment: @tchrist I should seldom be so presumptuous.